# Entity mapping issue

Tags: asp.net, automapper

When post gets triggered, it does not save user first and the last name. I have a user class, which inherits from identityuser class and i have declared two properties first and last name as in the code snippet. But problem is when I add the post to the repo it does not save user name rather it shows null value, which throws an exception.

I don't understand how to map, so that user name gets saved in the database.

```
 public abstract class AuditableEntity
 {
            [Required]
            public string Title { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime PostCreatedDate { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public User User { get; set; }  
        }

   public class TechPost : AuditableEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }


    }   

    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


    }
    public class TechPostCreation
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostCreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    public IActionResult CreatePost([FromBody] TechPostCreation techCreatePost)
    {
        if (techCreatePost == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var techPostEntity = _mapper.Map<TechPost>(techCreatePost);
        _repo.AddTechBlogPost(techPostEntity);

        if (!_repo.Save())
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "A problem happend and could handle your request");
        }

        var techPostReturn = _mapper.Map<TechPostViewModel>(techPostEntity);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetTechPost", new { id = techPostReturn.Id },
                techPostReturn);

    }

    public RepoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<TechPost, TechPostViewModel>()
                 .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                   $"{src.User.FirstName} {src.User.LastName}"));

        CreateMap<TravelPost, TravelPostViewModel>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                   $"{src.User.FirstName} {src.User.LastName}"));

        CreateMap<TechPostCreation, TechPost>();

    }
```

Comment: That sounds more like a model binding issue if the values don't make it from the view to the controller. Show the name fields in the view and your controller POST.

Comment: There isn't any problem with the binding, because when my post gets triggered it binds all the properties declared in the TechPostCreation class but when it tries to Map with <TechPost>, which inherits from abstract class AuditableEntity.  Problems start at "var techPostEntity = _mapper.Map<TechPost>(techCreatePost)", which does not hold/save user name. I don't know it is a problem with AutoMapper projection or something else. I post the value through postman :-

Comment: { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y" , "postCreatedDate", "today's date", "title": "anything", "description": "story" }

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var techPostEntity = _mapper.Map<TechPost>(techCreatePost);
```

Uses this map:

```
CreateMap<TechPostCreation, TechPost>();
```

Since your `User` class is a child of TechPost, you need a MapFrom clause. You may instead be able to rename the fields to UserFirstName/UserLastName so the convention kicks in.

Change your map:

```
CreateMap<TechPostCreation, TechPost>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.User.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.User.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName));
```

Also, I am not sure what your repo is doing, but you may need to retrieve or create the `User` with a UserManager at some point in your process.